# What version of ksh ships with AIX 5.3?

Tags: aix, shell-scripting, ksh

I'm writing a Korn shell script for a client, who will use it on AIX 5.3. For testing, I'm using [version 93u-1](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/ksh) Debian Wheezy. Is this the same version as the one I'll find on AIX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In summary, no.

```
oslevel -s
5300-08-03-0831
```

`/usr/bin/ksh` - Version M-11/16/88

`/usr/bin/ksh93` - Version M-12/28/93

The version may differ slightly between different TL/SP levels in AIX.  AIX by default uses ksh, and very little uses ksh93.  Obviously, you can configure your script to use `/usr/bin/ksh93`.  `/usr/bin/ksh93` is provided by the same fileset which provides the other shells (`bos.rte.shell`).

Comment: Thanks, I'll fallback to `ksh93` is my script needs it. In the mean time I found information about both ksh93 and ksh: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds3/ksh.htm